# How can i add a completion handler to this function?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a function which calls it's self if conditions are not met (which works perfectly fine) but now i want to add a completionHandler to it, I've already tried but different ways but the completion is never returned is any of the ways I've attempted.
**runSearch()**

```
func runSearch(){
    search{
        _ in
        if (parResults.count < 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.runSearch()//Run search again**
        }
        if (parResults.count >= 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.searchComplete = true
        }
    }
}
```

### What I've tried

**runSearch() with completionHandler call**

```
self.runSearch{
  msg in
print("all done") //Not executed
}
```

**runSearch() with completionHandler func 1**

```
func runSearch(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> () {
    search{
        _ in
        if (parResults.count < 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.runSearch{
                _ in
            }
        }
        if (parResults.count >= 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.searchComplete = true
            completionHandler(true)// Never returned
        }

    }
}
```

**runSearch() with completionHandler func 2**

```
 func runSearch(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> () {
    search{
        _ in
        if (parResults.count < 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.runSearch{
                _ in
                if (parResults.count >= 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
                    self.searchComplete = true
                    completionHandler(true)//Not returned
                }
            }
        }
        if (parResults.count >= 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.searchComplete = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you have too much confusing boilerplate cod ein your question, remove as much unnecessary if conditions as possible shrinking the code to the bare minimum that makes the question understandable. Right now I do not know what you *currently* have and what exactly you would want to achieve.

Comment: @luk2302 question has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your `completionHandler` down the line for each new call to `runSearch`:

```
func runSearch(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) {
    search{
        _ in
        if (parResults.count < 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.runSearch(completionHandler) // <-------
        } else if (parResults.count >= 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.searchComplete = true
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. Could you please explain how "passing it down the line" works?

Comment: @george what I mean is that you simply should pass it as a parameter for the next calls as my code does. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

```
func runSearch(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> () {
    search{
        _ in
        if (parResults.count < 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.runSearch(completionHandler)
        }
        if (parResults.count >= 20 && self.searchCounter < 20){
            self.searchComplete = true
            completionHandler(true)// Never returned
        }
        if (parResults.count == 0 && self.searchCounter == 20){
            self.noResultsFound = true
            completionHandler(true) //Never returned
        }
        if (parResults.count != 0 && self.searchCounter == 20){
            self.searchComplete = true
            completionHandler(true) // Never returned
        }
    }
}
```